# File not found AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, linkage

I am writing a program in AS3. It's exact contents don't seem to matter here. I basically have 4 classes, split in 4 files. Thing is, it can't find one of these files, and I can't understand why. I have checked it several times and even had my teacher check it, and we still can't find what is wrong with it. Did anyone else have a similar problem, or have any idea on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Line 37 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: CustomTextField.
Line 37 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method CustomTextField. (Twice)

```
package
{
    // Import stuff
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.*;

public class CustomButton extends MovieClip
{
    // Private variables:

    private var animationsListAR_:Array = [];// Array for the animations.
    private var textArea_:CustomTextField = new CustomTextField();
    private var curState_:int = 1;// The current state (1 = Normal, 2 = Pressed, 3 = Over).
    private var active_:Boolean;
    private var type_:String;// Multi choice, single choice, normal.
    private var group_:int;
    private var animated_:Boolean = false;

    // Protected variables:
    // Public variables:

    // Constructor:
    // This constructor sets up the event listeners and the button's properties.
    public function CustomButton( animationAR:Array, buttonlabel:String = "Hello", animated:Boolean = false, active:Boolean = true, type:String = "free", group:int = 0 )
    {
        this.gotoAndStop( curState_ );

        // Prevents the start of the animations.

        // Deals with the text inside the button.
        this.buttonMode = true;
        active_ = active;
        this.addChild( textArea_ );


        if (animated == true)
        {
            animated_ = true;
            /*
            animationsListAR_[0] = 1;

            for (var i:int = 1; i < animationAR.length; i++)
            {
            animationsListAR_[i] = animationAR[i - 1];
            }
            */
        }

        // If active_ is true the game will add EventListeners to this object.
        if (active_ == true)
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseOverHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutHandler);
        }

        // Needed to monitor the active_ var.
        this.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, activeChangeHandler);
    }

    // This function swaps the active_ variable value and calls activeChangeHandler.
    public function ActiveChange()
    {
        active_ = ! active_;
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
    }

    public function mouseOverHandler( evt:MouseEvent )
    {
        if(evt.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)
        {
            curState_ = 2;

            if (animated_ == true)
            {
                loopSegment( ( animationsListAR_[1] + 1 ), animationsListAR_[2] );
            }
            else
            {
                this.gotoAndStop( curState_ );
            }

            this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function( evt:MouseEvent ):void
                                  {
                                      evt.target.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arguments.callee );
                                      curState_ = 3;
                                      evt.target.gotoAndStop( curState_ );
                                  });
        }

        else if( evt.buttonDown != true )
        {
            curState_ = 3;

            if (animated_ == true)
            {
                loopSegment( ( animationsListAR_[2] + 1 ), animationsListAR_[3] );
            }
            else
            {
                this.gotoAndStop( curState_ );
            }
        }

        dispatchEvent(new CustomButtonEvent(CustomButtonEvent.OVER));
    }

    public function mouseOutHandler(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        curState_ = 1;

        if (animated_ == true)
        {
            loopSegment( ( animationsListAR_[0] ), animationsListAR_[1] );
        }
        else
        {
            this.gotoAndStop( curState_ );
        }

        dispatchEvent(new CustomButtonEvent(CustomButtonEvent.OUT));
    }

    public function activeChangeHandler(evt:Event)
    {
        if (active_ == true)
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mouseOverHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mouseOverHandler);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutHandler);
        }

        // modifyMaskButton();
    }

    /*
    public function modifyMaskButton():void
    {
    if (active_ = true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    }
    */
    public function playSegment( begin:int, end:int ):void
    {
        if (begin != end)
        {
            gotoAndPlay( begin );
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function( evt:Event ):void
                    {
                        if( currentFrame == end )
                        {
                            stop();
                            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
                        }
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            this.gotoAndStop( end );
        }
    }

    // This loops continuosly an animation. Should, at least...
    public function loopSegment( begin:int, end:int ):void
    {
        if (begin != end)
        {
            gotoAndPlay( begin );
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function( evt:Event ):void
                    {
                        if( currentFrame == end )
                        {
                            gotoAndPlay( begin );
                        }
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            this.gotoAndStop( end );
        }
    }
}
}
```

Second File:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class CustomTextField extends MovieClip
{
    private var textArea:TextField;
    private var boldText:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

    function CustomTextField()
    {
        textArea = new TextField;
    }

    override function CustomTextfield( labelText:String, font:String = "Arial", color:uint = 0xFFFFFFFF, size:uint = 10 )
    {
        textArea = new TextField;
        boldText.font = font;
        boldText.color = color;
        boldText.size = size;
        this.text = labelText;
    }

    function changeFont( font:String ):void
    {
        boldText.font = font;
        updateText();
    }

    function changeColor( color:uint ):void
    {
        boldText.color = color;
        updateText();
    }

    function changeSize( size:uint ):void
    {
        boldText.size = size;
        updateText();
    }

    function embedText( choice:Boolean ):void
    {
        this.embedFonts = choice;
    }

    function updateText():void
    {
        this.setTextFormat( boldText );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't expect to get an answer for a question, that merely says that you have a problem. Give us error messages, a description of the project structure and/or the sourcecode itself. Try to break down your problem in something easily understood.

Comment: @twall This is not only helpful for us, but often when you break down your problem, you end up finding the answer.

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone would say "Ah yes, it's a known Flash problem when you have 4 files", you should describe things a little further.

Comment: Other comments are right,  post the code. Have you checked the name of the files and the name of classes are the same?

Comment: Of course I checked several times all the links, name, paths, etc., or I wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line in the second file:

```
 override function CustomTextfield( labelText:String, font:String = "Arial"
```

"CustomTextfield" // should be "CustomTextField",within your script missing the capital letter.

I think your getting 2 errors as this function is triggered twice within script or some related change it and let us know.

Comment: Of course it's in the same directory. Yes, they are properly referenced. Anyway, I added the source code.

Comment: I made new .as and .fla files, then copy&pasted everything. It found the file. I still dunno what it could be. Anyway, the line above fixed the error that appeared afterwards.

Comment: well i still helped ,lol could of been a bug from memory..iv had weird things happen in cs5,loaded content suddenly stop apearing with no errors, so i had to start again like your self.hope is all well..I voted 1 up :)